# Django how to make a reverse foreign key reference

Tags: python, django, backend

I building an online testing system, I currently have 2 tables:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    answer = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    .....
    answer = ForeinKey(Answer)
```

and I have the ModelAdmin

```
class AnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
```

Im making the admin site for it. What i want is that each time the users go to the question, the site only displays the appropriate answer related to it and users are able to edit the answer(pop up the AnswerAdmin windows). I have tried to override the `formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs)` and `change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None)` in `QuestionAdmin`to narrow down the queryset and pass the related answer to the template but it didnt work because I dont know what to put in the `Answer.objects.filter(ID = ???)`. Any idea? Also tried using form.

Update:
I have made this: using

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Question
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['answer'].queryset = Answer.objects.filter(ID =  self.instance.answer.ID)
```

to override the form in QuestionAdmin and add a context to the template:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['ID'] = object_id
    return super(QuestionAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
        extra_context=extra_context)
```

It works but it require the Answer ID to be the same with the Question ID reference to it, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Question
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['answer'].queryset = Answer.objects.filter(ID =  self.instance.answer.ID)
```

to override the form in QuestionAdmin and add a context to the template:

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    extra_context = extra_context or {}
    extra_context['ID'] = object_id
    return super(QuestionAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
        extra_context=extra_context)
```

It works but it require the Answer ID to be the same with the Question ID reference to it, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the view, have you considered to use the admin's builtin [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) functionality?

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

**admin.py**

```
class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerInline]

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

This way you actually need only one admin class (for your Question model) and the answers are always in place. Just a thought, it's something i use heavily in my projects.

Comment: You are doing it in the reverse way django support, you can only ad inlines of Question in the AnswerAdmin

Comment: Dirk Eschler seems to have it right.  Typically you have a question with many answers, and thus an answer with a foreign key to question.  This results in a question admin with answer inlines.  OP has answer and question defined in the opposite way, with questions pointing to answers.  Dirk's inlines work for his models, but not for the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).  You can filter on other keys besides ID.
Your code would probably be something like `Answer.objects.filter(question = myquestion)`

Answer (score 0):

One possibe approach is to use [modelchoicefield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Something like this:

```
def get_question_admin_form(the_q):
    class QuestionAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        answers = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Answers",
                queryset=Question.objects.filter(pk=the_q.pk).answer_set.all())

        # ... other fields

        class Meta:
            model = Question

    return QuestionAdminForm

class QuestionAdmin(admin.modelAdmin):
    model = Question

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj is not None:
            self.form = get_question_admin_form(obj)
        return super(QuestionAdmin, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
```